# How to get the right value?

Tags: c++, string, list, math, structure

What must I do to get the right Level?

example:

```
int gXP = globalDoHandle::PlayerStats_XP(p);
ostringstream sXP; sXP << "XP(RP): " << gXP;

ostringstream sLEVEL; sLEVEL << "Level: " << gLEVEL;
```

I want use the XP value to get the right Level then.
If I get the the value 24450 should give me it then "10" back
I know I can use something like this, but that are 8000 Level in the Game!

```
if (gXP < 800) { Rank = "1"; }
else if (gXP < 2100) { Rank = "2"; }
else if (gXP < 3800) { Rank = "3"; }
...

LEVEL: XP
Level 1: 0
Level 2: 800
Level 3: 2100
Level 4: 3800
Level 5: 6100
Level 6: 9500
Level 7: 12500
Level 8: 16000
Level 9: 19800
Level 10: 24000
Level 11: 28500
Level 12: 33400
Level 13: 38700
Level 14: 44200
Level 15: 50200
Level 16: 56400
Level 17: 63000
Level 18: 69900
Level 19: 77100
Level 20: 84700
...Level 8000: 1787576850
```

Comment: What is the formula used to create the experience table? If you have an array of those values just index through it and look for the last value that's less than your experience value.

Comment: please put your attempt

Comment: I have nothing atm... Have you any Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do such a job, you need [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). `std::lower_bound(l, h, v)` returns an iterator `it` inside the range `[l, h)` for which the value on the range is the smallest verifying `*it > v`.

```
constexpr std::array<unsigned, 10> levels = { /* ... */ }; // xp needed for each level

unsigned level(unsigned xp)
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound(cbegin(levels), cend(levels), xp);
    return std::distance(begin(levels), it);
}
```

`level(xp)` returns the level reached with `xp` experience points with respect to the values of `levels`.

[Se a full demo online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf7227f2ce35d1b9)

Comment: From there, getting a string representation of the returned value is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::array` with your exp values in.

```
std::array<int, 8000> exp_table = { 0, 800, 2100... };

int level=0;
for(; level < exp_table.size() && exp_table[level] < gXP; ++level);

Rank = std::to_string(level); // If this is needed?
```

After this `level` will be set correctly. The only thing left is how you generate your `exp_table`. Read it from a file. Use some math formula.